# Using global variables in Puppet with roles/profiles without overriding in node-definition

Tags: roles, puppet

I'm currently building a new puppet repository with Craig Dunn's roles/profiles paradigm and ran into a (foreseeable) problem trying to reduce node definitions to only include their role.

I'm working with global variables (default defined at top scope) for basic differentiations in common classes (eg. determine which users get ssh access). But since I don't want to override them in the node definition I'm searching for a nice way to set them in the profiles.

Basically my problem is the static scoping of puppet: I can't just override them in the role classes since it won't get inherited to the children like it was with dynamic scopes and I can't call upon the qualified name in the modules since I don't know from which class it's called.

My ideas I had so far to solve the problem:

1. Define the roles in top scope and override the variables there
   This would probably be the dirty workaround if everything else fails. Though I'm not sure if the classes would get some kind of sub-top-scope with the ability to actually override it.
2. Find out if hiera is able to see what module/class hierarchy called it and give me the corresponding value(s). Sadly I haven't been able to find a decent documentation/tutorial for hiera yet.
3. Create an inheritance hell - I would prefer not to and thinking about it, it doesn't even seem possible
4. Create a parameterisized-classes hell - with time there will be a lot of variables to pass through which leads to a lot of redundancy and error sources
5. Make top scope classes that get included in the profiles. Though again I'm not sure this would work (see 1))

Does anyone have a nice solution for this that is as undirty as possible? Or can you confirm one of the ideas I have?

Btw.: I want to reduce the node definitions to the role including because I want to use the puppet dashboard as ENC and for logging soon.

Answer (score 1):

Have you thought about adding a hierarchy level to Hiera called Roles?

To make this work you need to either:

1. Add a variable in your Node definition defining which Role is the current one
2. Add a fact to the Node with the Role

This would enable Hiera to pick up a specific yaml file for that Role. In this file you can specify the users.

You could also do this at profile level.

Comment: This doens't have to be a yaml file it could be json obviously.

Comment: Sounds like @Chris is really overcomplicating things a bit here. This should be attainable through a hiera hierarchy rather than global variables.